# efficient way to aggregationresult

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

It's my example ..

```
items: [
  {
   mart_code : 1,
   director: "James",
   category: "fruit",
   name: "apple",
   money: 5000
  },
  {
   mart_code: 1
   director: "James",
   category: "toy",
   name: "dragon",
   money: 15000
  },
  {
   mart_code: 2,
   director: "Sam",
   category: "fruit",
   name: "orange",
   money: 3500
  }
]
```

I want to get result..

```
martList: [ {
  mart_code: 1,
  directorList:[
  {
   director: "James",
   money: 20000
  }
  ],
  categoryList: [
  {
   category: "fruit",
   money: 5000
  },
  {
   category: "toy",
   money: 15000
  }] 
},
{
  mart_code: 2,
  directorList:[
  {
   director: "Sam",
   money: 3500
  }
  ],
  categoryList: [
  {
   category: "fruit",
   money: 3500
  }]
}
]
```

I trying to $facet, and $group, $unwind $project...
Is there an efficient way?

Comment: why apply my top example auto-senstance ....? sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Hope **$group** and **$project** would be effective way of getting result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group : {
    _id : {
        mart_code : '$mart_code',
        director : '$director',
        category : '$category'
        },
    money: {$sum : '$money'}
}},
{$group : {
    _id : '$_id.mart_code',
    directorList : {$push : {
        director: "$_id.director",
        money: '$money'
    }},
    categoryList : {$push : {
        category: "$_id.category",
        money: '$money'
    }}
}},
{$group : {
    _id : null,
     martList : {$push : {
        mart_code : '$_id',
        directorList : '$directorList',
        categoryList : '$categoryList'
    }}
}},
{$project : {
    _id : 0,
    martList : '$martList'
}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is incorrect...
Money don't sum ..
I want to group for money-sum, And group from mart_code ..

Comment: I modified, could you check

Comment: Thank you.. but.. Is this correct ?
directorList in mart_code 1 are {James, 5000}, {James, 15000} ..
I wanna get {James, 20000} in mart_code 1 ..

Answer (score 0):

I tried this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$items" },
{$group : {
    _id : {
        mart_code : '$mart_code',
        director : '$director'
        },
    money: {$sum : '$money'},
    entry: {$push: {$$ROOT}}
}},
{$group : {
    _id : '$_id.mart_code',
    directorList : {$push : {
        director: "$_id.director",
        money: '$money'
    }},
    entry: {$push: "$entry"}
}},
{ $unwind : "$entry" },
{ $unwind : "$entry" },
{$group : {
    _id : {
        mart_code : '$_id',
        directorList : '$directorList',
        category : '$entry.category'
    },
    money: {$sum: "$entry.money"}
}},
{$group: {
    _id: {
        mart_code : '$_id',
        directorList : '$directorList',
    },
    categoryList:{ $push:{
      category: "$_id.category",
      money: "$money"
    }}
}}
{$project : {
    _id : 0,
    categoryList: "$categoryList",
    directorList: "$_id.directoryList"
}}
])
```

It's so no efficient way.....